# OpenVPN bridged mode connects, but only ping of VPN server possible

Tags: openvpn

I know this has been asked a lot before, but all the other questions did not solve my problem.

My scenario: I have some servers which are connected in a network with the IP addresses `10.10.10.x`. One of them has a second NIC that is `192.168.1.1`.

What I want:

- Connect to 192.168.1.1 from Windows
- Get an IP address in the 10.10.10.x range
- Be able to access everything on 10.10.10.x
- Be able to access my Windows client from the server

Here is my `server.conf`:

```
port 1194
proto udp
server-bridge 10.10.10.1 255.255.255.0 10.10.10.20 10.10.10.30
dev tap0
ca /etc/openvpn/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/keys/dh1024.pem
up /etc/openvpn/bridge-start
keepalive 10 600
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
verb 3
mute 20
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log
script-security 2
client-to-client

# The server doesn't need privileges
user openvpn
group openvpn
```

Here is the `bridge-start` script:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Set up Ethernet bridge on Linux

# Requires: bridge-utils

echo "adding $1 to bridge"

/usr/sbin/brctl addif br0 $1
/usr/sbin/ifconfig $1 up
```

Here is an excerpt from the `client.ovpn` I use to connect with Windows:

```
client
dev tap
proto udp
remote 192.168.1.1 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

(After this, the certificate info starts)

When I connect, the OpenVPN GUI tells me that I get the IP address `10.10.10.20` assigned. I can ping `10.10.10.1` from the Windows computer, and on the VPN server, I can ping `10.10.10.20`. However, I don't reach any other computer, for example, `10.10.10.101`, and from the `10.10.10.101` I also cannot reach `10.10.10.20`.

IP forwarding is already active, and I configured `eth1` and `br0` beforehand:

Network script for eth1:

```
TYPE="Ethernet"
BOOTPROTO="none"
IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL="no"
NAME="eth1"
DEVICE="eth1"
ONBOOT="yes"
BRIDGE=br0
```

Script for `br0`:

```
TYPE="Bridge"
BOOTPROTO="none"
NAME="br0"
DEVICE="br0"
ONBOOT="yes"
IPADDR="10.10.10.1"
PREFIX="16"
```

### Followup 1

I tried to capture the traffic with `tcpdump` and this is what a `ping 10.10.10.101` from my Windows box yields:

```
# tcpdump -n -i br0
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on br0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes
15:24:26.893313 ARP, Request who-has 10.10.10.101 tell 10.10.10.20, length 28
15:24:27.763926 ARP, Request who-has 10.10.10.101 tell 10.10.10.20, length 28
15:24:28.763943 ARP, Request who-has 10.10.10.101 tell 10.10.10.20, length 28
```

So it seems the packets arrive at the VPN server, but it doesn't answer.

What am I missing?

Comment: How do the computers at `10.10.10.0/24` network get their IP addresses?

Comment: They have fixed ones

Comment: Do you have `ipv4.forwarding` enabled in kernel?

Comment: Yes, I have. But in the meantime, I dumped the configuration and used the `tun` based one described at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-and-configure-an-openvpn-server-on-centos-7 and it works just fine. From my servers, I can reach the Windows computer at 10.8.0.6.